# How do you breed a Butterfly dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

So a new limited time dragon has been added to DragonVale, namely the Butterfly dragon. I see this is a tri-combination dragon using Air, Lightning and Fire. With the last few dragons however simply matching these elements has proven to not be effective. What is a good combination of dragons to produce this type of dragon?

Comment: I would add a "and how do I know I have one" because it is always interesting to know the incubation time.

Comment: Fly little butterfly. _Fly!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers from @Arremer and @EBongo below contain vital information so I can not accept one over the other, to that end here is that information combined:

Overview information from @Arremer

> Popular combinations:
>
> - **Firefly Dragon + Air dragon**
> - **Sonic dragon + Firefly Dragon**
>
> You need to be level 14.
>
> Breeding butterfly dragon takes place in a normal breeding cave or on the breeding island.
>
> Breeding time: 12 hours

A specific addition from @EBongo

> **Firefly is a requirement**
>
> It has been confirmed multiple places that one Firefly dragon is a requirement to breed this dragon. So your options are Firefly + Air or Firefly + Air Hybrid. For Air Hybrids, Sonic and Blazing have both been reported to work. They are probably best, since they do not introduce any new elements.
>
> Sources:
> [Here](http://w11.zetaboards.com/dragonvale/topic/7807794/1/)
> [and Here](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Butterfly_Dragon)

Comment: Blazing and firefly worked for me first try but then could not duplicate result a second time

Answer (score 4):

Popular combinations:

- **Firefly Dragon + Air dragon**
- **Firefly Dragon + Sonic dragon**

You need to be level 14.

Breeding butterfly dragon takes place in a normal breeding cave or on the breeding island.

Breeding time: 12 hours

Answer (score 2):

**Firefly is a requirement**

It has been confirmed multiple places that one Firefly dragon is a requirement to breed this dragon. So your options are Firefly + Air or Firefly + Air Hybrid. For Air Hybrids, Sonic and Blazing have both been reported to work. They are probably best, since they do not introduce any new elements.

Sources:
[Here](http://w11.zetaboards.com/dragonvale/topic/7807794/1/) 
[and Here](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Butterfly_Dragon)

Comment: As a footnote, I got both of mine from Firefly + Air, at the EBI.

Answer (score 2):

To breed a butterfly dragon, on the right side, put the firefly dragon, and in the left, the sonic dragon to get the butterfly dragon.